# How to get a relative path in a web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I searched around stackoverflow on how to make a relative file and have tried various things and it hasn't worked, and i was hoping to see if you guys could help me out.

here is my connection sting in my web.config file:

```
 <add name="2007 Database  05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24)
  ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
  Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

and here relative path in my `aspx` file:

```
<script runat="server">
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["2007 Database 
    05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24) ConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString + Server.MapPath("..\..\Anderson\2007 
    Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb");
</script>
```

And I get this error: `CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence`

So what exactly am I doing wrong

Comment: I wouldn't use a `'` in a connection string. And I wouldn't use an apostrophe on a directory name even though is supported just because many libraries don't handle this quite well. Try removing it and see if that helps.

Comment: I would start by choosing a simple and short name value, which does not contain any special characters.

Comment: I get this error now  CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

Answer (score 1):

You aren't escaping the "\" character in your path so it is causing an error in the `MapPath()` method.

Change this:

`Server.MapPath("..\..\Anderson\2007 Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb"`

to this:

`Server.MapPath(@"..\..\Anderson\2007 Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb"`

or this:

`Server.MapPath("..\\..\\Anderson\\2007 Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb"`

Comment: When I change it to the first method I get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure that `ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["2007 Database 
    05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24) ConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString` is returning a valid value?

Comment: Remove the part in bold and see if you still get the Object reference error: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["2007 Database 
    05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24) ConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString **+ Server.MapPath("..\..\Anderson\2007 
    Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb");**

Comment: Ya I still get the same error, so what exactly does this mean?

Comment: It means that your call to `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[...]` is not returning anything. You need to check the name of the connection string in your config file to call it correctly. If your connection string looks something like `<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Target" 
      connectionString="server=MYSERVER; Database=MYDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>` then you would access is like this `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Target"]`

Comment: @Brian Ok so I fixed that, and now it says: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Comment: Now I get DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D).

Comment: Sounds like you've got some other deeper problems going on. You will have to submit a new question for that to be handled, but please mark this answer as correct if it solved the problem for which this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using \ in your path string but thats the symbol for literal.
So any char following the \ will be inturpreted as a literal like \. is not a valid char.
You actualy want the literal \ the sequence for which is \\ 
Also @ infront of a string tells that you dont want literals.

So mappath(" needs to be mappath(@" or every \ needs to become \\

Comment: could you please explain that better

Comment: When I change it to this: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2007 Database 05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24) ConnectionString"].ConnectionString + Server.MapPath(@"..\..\Anderson\2007 Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb"); I get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.